# "be oriented toward" something

Tags: sentence-construction

> Now, I'm oriented toward learning engineering and then using it actively in practice.

Does this sentence make sense? Is it grammatical?

Comment: For AmE, it's fine. BrE would normally use ***towards***.

Comment: It has about the highest "cop-out" value possible in a positive statement.  In other words If I'm oriented North that means I pointing North, but I could be taking a nap in that orientation, rather than actively moving North.  So saying that you're "oriented towards learning engineering" is basically saying that if you were to do anything you likely would do that, but it doesn't actually say you're doing it- you're just oriented towards it.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the sentence makes grammatical sense, but sounds a bit confused. I'd suggest something like the following:

> I'm currently focused on learning engineering, with a goal to use it actively in practice.

You might even drop the "focused on"; it doesn't add much if anything to the meaning.

In addition, the term "engineering" isn't generally something you learn as a whole; it's just too darn big. You might want to specify a discipline of engineering (e.g. "software engineering" "civil engineering", etc).

Answer (score 3):

That sentence sounds completely fine.

Being oriented toward something means that you're focused on it, or that it's your goal ([freedictionary definition #4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/orient)).

Making a reference to orientation - which conjures thoughts of maps, directions, and finding your way - makes sense if you're talking about your life goals, especially if they've changed recently.